# Xcode: Can't Attach to process

Tags: xcode, debugging

After I plugged my iPhone into my mac, I started debugging my app. For the first few days, it all seemed smooth.
But after a few days, things changed.
The `Debug` -> `Attach to process` menu is empty, as shown below. I can't figure out why.

But the weirder thing is that when I debugged my app three months later, the processes on my iPhone were correctly listed on the `Attach to process` menu, but they all disappeared again after a few days.

My device configuration is: iPhone 6 - iOS 12 - macOS Sonoma 14.3.1 - Xcode 15.2

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfmJy.png)

I can't wait a few months before I have a chance to debug my app. So I had to ask for help here.

Comment: If you think Xcode is behaving incorrectly, file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Do you have a paid Apple Developer membership?

Comment: To @matt , I don't know how to report it to apple.
And I have paid $99 per year.

Comment: Can you simply build and run the app from Xcode to your iPhone while the iPhone is connected to your Mac? That's a lot easier than trying to use the "Attach to process" menu.

Comment: To @HangarRash , yes I can. but my App contain a `Network Extension`, I must to attach it manually. So I have to use `Attach to process by PID or Name...` menu item now. It's a bad experience.